# node js crone job is not working first day of every month

Tags: node.js, express, cron

```
cron.schedule('* * * 1 *', function () {//do something })
```

this is my code for cron job, it supposed to trigger the first day of every month. but it won't be doing anything what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the expression config from the below image.

If you write like this **"* * * * *"** it will run for every minute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That cron runs

> At every minute in January.

https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_1_*

You should use `0 * 1 * *`

> At minute 0 on day-of-month 1